# Regarding iterator list giving invalid data after type casted from one pointer object type to another pointer object type

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, type-conversion, typecast-operator

I am trying to get data from iterator list which is pointing to a list of pointer object of A type.
And this data is assigning to pointer object of B type.

Code:

```
   A* a=new A();
   B* b=new B();
   std::list<A*>a_list;
   for(std::list<A*> iterator it = a_list.begin(); it != a_list.end(); it++) {
          b= (B*)(*it); }
```

In this, i am getting correct value in (*it), but after above type conversion, most of the data is invalid. It is giving some random garbage value.

I have tried the type conversion of **interpret_cast**, but still it is giving me the same invalid data.

Comment: How exactly is it giving "some random garbage'? And why would you ever think that conversion from A to B is valid?

Comment: Please provide expected and actual output from your problem code